# removing 0 while forming dataframe using as.data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

```
 as.data.frame(table(f1$Fresh.email.date, f1$Country, f1$Company.Size, f1$Vertical, f1$X1st.Follow.up, f1$X2nd.Follow.up, f1$X3rd.Follow.up))...
```

and remove the freq with 0 count in forming this dataframe

Comment: are you sure you are creating mutlidimensional `table`

Comment: Yes, multidimensional table in a dataframe, is there any other option?

Comment: I need to get the freq of the emails sent

Comment: I think you need `f1 %>% group_by(Country, Company.Size, Vertical, ..) %>% summarise(n = n())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can either use `count` or a `group_by` `n()`

```
library(dplyr)
f1 %>% 
   group_by_at(nm1) %>%
   summarise(n = n())
```

where,

```
nm1 <- c("Country", "Company.Size", "Vertical", "X1st.Follow.up", 
    "X2nd.Follow.up",  "X3rd.Follow.up")
```